# Laravel 5.0 Unit Testing problems with Session variables

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I am trying to do some unit testing on some existing code. My controller looks something like

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        if (!Session::get('answers', [])) {
            App::abort(403, 'Error.');
        }

        // Do rest of the stuff here
    }
}
```

and my test class looks something like

```
class DefaultController extends extends TestCase {
    public function testIndex_withoutSession() {
        // Arrange
        /* Nothing to arrange now */

        // Act
        $this->action('GET', 'DefaultController@index');

        // Assert
        $this->assertResponseStatus(403);
    }

    public function testIndex_withSession() {
        // Arrange
        $this->session(['answers' => array()]);

        // Act
        $this->action('GET', 'ParticipantController@create');

        $this->assertSessionHas('answers');
        // this function is giving true

        // Assert
        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);

        $this->flushSession();
    }
}
```

My test cases without the session is working fine but when I want to check it by mocking the session variable 'answers' it is still giving me the error. Can anyone please help me out by figuring what am I doing wrong or how can I do it properly? Without this I cannot proceed any further in checking the code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `answer` typo, the answers array needs at least one element in order to pass your falsey check in the controller. The Test Case will not assert 200.

Either add a value in the test case:

```
$this->session(['answers' => array('something')]);
```

Or change the controller:

```
if (!Session::has('answers')) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As while testing it is never to touch the main existing codes, I changed it in my testing function. And now it is working very well.

Answer (score 0):

You have `$this->session(['answers' => array()]);` 
But you are looking for answer instead of answers here `$this->assertSessionHas('answer');` 
The extra or the missing 's' in answer is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was just a typo while rewriting this code. But was still failing. @MrCode 's solution gave me the result. I am editing my typo in the code as if someone else is searching it will get a good solution from here.